# Can't use Arctic P311 bluetooth headset

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth, headset

I am using the Arctic P311 headset, with a Rocketfish bluetooth mini USB adapter. The operating system is Windows 7 64 bit SP1.

The headset seems to be detected fine by the adapter. The computer says that the device is connected when I pair it up with the computer as it appears in the list of devices under the Control Panel. However, after pairing when it tries to install drivers, it says drivers cannot be found. Additionally, when I try to direct sound to the device, the P311 does not appear under the list of playback options.

Looking at the device properties, it says:
The drivers for this device are not installed. (Code 28)

There is no driver selected for the device information set or element.

To find a driver for this device, click Update Driver.

Clicking on update driver gives a further message that the device driver cannot be found.

I know the headset works because I can pair it with my Iphone 4 and ASUS Transformer tablet fine.

Answer (score 0):

I also had this issue with RocketFish. I finally ended up hiring tech support who eventually got it working by manually installing the driver from the CD it came with. The auto run file was apparently corrupted and tried to update the drivers without first installing them.

Answer (score -1):

Most of the time, Windows manages to find a driver for most things without issues. Not always the best one; not always the most up to date one, but most of the time, it works. But sometimes, it just can't, and you need to find the driver yourself. To do that, you can use:

- Whatever disc came with your device
- The device maker's website
- A program that looks through all of your devices/drivers and sees if there are updates to be performed.

Install the driver manually and everything should go fine.

Comment: No disc came with the artic p311. I checked the device webpage and no driver is available for download.

Can you name an example of the a program that does what you described (ideally free)?

Comment: Uhm, as for the website, uhm. That's super weird. It's the first time I see the website of a hardware maker that doesn't even have drivers. I'm ehm. Weirded out. This topic might help you. You could try to browse through it. --- http://www.techsupportforum.com/forums/f19/drivers-for-arctic-sound-p311-headset-620554.html --- As for driver updating software, here: http://alternativeto.net/software/driver-genius/ ~ pick one, I guess!